# Loading debug information from another pre-built solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, symbols

I have a Visual Studio solution (C#) which represents the core of our application.  We build this and it comprises about 10 or so DLLs with corresponding PDBs.

I have several other VS solutions each of which is used for a customer of ours.  These VS solutions use the core DLLs and add their own bits as required.  The "core" has the main .exe so we do the following in customer specific solution

- Post build step in the a project to copy the EXE/DLLs/PDBs into the $(TargetDir)
- Set project debug settings to "Start External Program" pointing to the .exe

This all works, tho seems a bit clumsy.

My questions are:

When running via the customer specific solution, how can I

- Have the code for the core project open automatically when I step into it
- Be able to open a core file and set a breakpoint

I'm used to Java where you reference the compiled and source jars/directories from the Java IDE and that's pretty much it.  How can do the same in visual studio (DLLs and PDBs)?

(I would prefer to avoid the GAC if possible because we sometimes have several local builds of the core around at the same time working on different projects)

Answer (score 1):

Mike, if you open an "higher in stack" solution which references a core solution, you can open the source file of the core solution and put a breakpoint in it, then when you debug the current solution Visual Studio is smart enough to step into and trigger your breakpoint if the .pdb files are available in the bin folder.

Comment: Thanks I will try this, however is there any way of doing this without the .cs files?  Does the PDB have enough information in it, in theory, to do this on its own?

Comment: pdb has debug symbols but not the source code, you need both.

Comment: Interesting, once a while ago I managed to get the core .NET framework code symbols loaded so I was able to debug into Control.cs and co.  Where did that information come from?  Is that some magic info that comes from the microsoft symbol server rather than PDBs?

Answer (score 1):

TO automatically have the debugging control traverse into the core source files, make sure to refer the core dlls from locally build core solution and make sure that have access to it.
Another way is after having the core dlls refered, just open the CS file in which you want to put a break point and debug.

Comment: I do reference the core DLLs (as in project references) and as described above the DLLs/PDBs are copied locally but the traversal doesn't happen.

Comment: Don't copy the core dlls to different bin location, just try to refer from the location where it was built.

Comment: Also make sure that the project configuration is set to debug before you compile it and see pdbs generated after the compilation (just a sanity check you know).

Comment: Definitely in Debug.  The DLLs are pulled in by Ivy into a lib dir.  I reference them there, however if I don't copy them then the project doesn't run because I am using "Start External Program" and it only looks for other DLLs in the same directory (bin/Debug).

Comment: could you try to create a sample application mimicking similar scenario. I am afraid, somehow it might have to do with some administrator privileges or some debugging option in VS for not loading Symbols files at runtime.